# php question checking pics format

Tags: php

I have problem to check picture format the code:

```
// 0 means a successful transfer
if ($_FILES["fname"]["error"] > 0) {
    $_FILES["fname"]["name"] = "holder.jpg";        // line 3
    $imgData = $hyperlink.$_FILES["fname"]["name"]; // line 4
} else {
    $imgData = $hyperlink.$_FILES["fname"]["name"];
}

// Only accept files of jpeg format
$img = substr($imgData, 37);
$_FILES["fname"]["type"] = $img;

print "****";

print $_FILES["fname"]["type"];

//print $img;

print "****";

// only accept jpg images pjpeg is for Internet Explorer.. should be jpeg
if (!($_FILES["fname"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || !($_FILES["fname"]["type"== "image/jpg")) {
    print "I only accept jpg files!"; 
    exit(0);
}
```

It always goes to the first `if` statment (line 3 and 4). If I don’t upload the pictures and when it goes to `if` statment to check the format and it gives me *I only accept jpg files*. My guess it accepts it as string so that it says *I only accept jpg files*.

Comment: Please format your code next time (see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

```
!($_FILES["fname"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || !($_FILES["fname"]["type"== "image/jpg")
```

is the same as

```
!( ($_FILES["fname"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") && ($_FILES["fname"]["type"== "image/jpg") )
```

In this form you can better see that $_FILES["fname"]["type"] can never be equal with both "image/pjpeg" and "image/jpeg" so the condition is always true.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to check that the file is ACTUALLY a jpeg, not that its mime type on submit was a jpeg.  Look into the [exif_imagetype()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) function, or [getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

```
<?php
  
  if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['fname']['tmp_name']) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    echo "Image is not a JPEG!";
    exit;
  }
```

If exif_imagetype isn't available, getimagesize should work:

```
<?php
   if ((list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['fname']['tmp_name'])) !== FALSE) {
     if ($type != IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
       echo "Image is not a JPEG!";
       exit;
     }
   }
```